# How to do a input validation with a string of array?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program where I have to input a month which follows with an output of how many days are in that month. However, I also have to write a code where if the input is not a valid month, it shows an error message. I haven't been able to figure out how to output that error statement. I already figured out the rest though.

I have tried the while loop, but it has not worked for me. I know I must be doing something wrong, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

   const int MONTHS = 12;
   int days[MONTHS] = { 31, 28, 31, 30,
                        31, 30, 31, 31,
                        30, 31, 30, 31 };
   string m;
   string i[MONTHS] = { "January", "February", "March",
                        "April", "May", "June", "July",
                        "August", "September", "October",
                        "November", "December" };

   cout << "Enter the name of the month: " << endl;
   cin >> m;

   while (m < MONTHS)
   {
       cout << "Invalid month entered! Exit the program to try again." 
            << endl;
   }

   cout << endl;
   for (int count = 0; count < MONTHS; count++)
       if (m == i[count])
       {
           cout << "There are " << days[count] << " days in "
                << i[count] << "." << endl;
       }

   return 0;
}
```

This is the expected result whenever the user inputs a invalid month.

```
Input the name of a month: Orion
Orion is not the name of a month.
```

Comment: Great question, but what does it do right now?

Comment: The most obvious problem is that your `while` loop will never end. The condition has no chance of changing within the body of the loop. You never ass for a new value of `m` from the user. Edit : It appears that the code won't actually compile. But the logic flaw is still relevant.

Comment: Consider adding `const` to `i` and `days` to avoid mistakes. Edit : Additionally, consider renaming the identifier `i` to a more meaningful name. `i` does not convey "list of months".

Comment: This program won't compile, will it? What is the intention of `while( m < MONTHS )`? This is comparing a string against an integer, which is nonsensical.

Comment: An error message keeps popping up in the build saying "no match for 'operator<'" next to the while loop. Edit: I thought `while(m < MONTHS)` will only catch the name of the months in the array above, but if there is a invalid month inputted, it will then output the error statement. It has not worked of course.

Comment: @Orion To use your example, if you provide `"Orion"` to `m`, what do you expect `"Orion" < 12` (`m < MONTH`) to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` loop is trying to compare `m` (a string) with `MONTHS` (the integer 12). Rather than try to fix that, my suggestion is to adjust the code following your `for` loop. You're already comparing `m` to each month in the array, right? If `m` matches, there's no need to continue looping, so you can simply `return` at that point. Then, if the `for` loop completes without a match, you know the month was invalid and can report it. Something like this:

```
for (int count = 0; count < MONTHS; count++)
   if (m == i[count])
   {
       cout << "There are " << days[count] << " days in "
            << i[count] << "." << endl;
       return 0;
   }
cout << m " is not the name of a month." << endl;
return 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is an assignment? For the main function you could use a map.
Here are some hints so you can complete the task.
Also remember that string comparison is case sensitive which needs to be addressed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <map>
struct comparer
{
   public:
   bool operator()(const std::string x, const std::string y) const
   {
        return x.compare(y)==0;
}
};
```

```
int main()
{

    map<string, int> months;

    months.insert(pair<string, int>("january", 31));
    months.insert(pair<string, int>("february", 28));
    months.insert(pair<string, int>("mars", 31));
    months.insert(pair<string, int>("april", 30));


    cout << "Enter the name of the month: " << endl;
    cin >> m;

    std::map<std::string, int, comparer>::iterator it=months.find(m);
    if(it!=months.end())
        printf("The number of days is %d\n",(*it).second);
    else
        printf("Error, the month not found\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of little problems contributing to your error.

The first is that you are comparing string `m` to int `MONTHS`. That won't work (possibly at all, but at the very least) the way you expect it.

Second, as others have mentioned, there is nothing inside your loop to end the loop. You will want to reset the value of m that way you don't get [an infinite loop](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/infinite-loop-endless-loop).

Here is a suggestion of something you could do that should work as you want it to:

**NOTE:** it requires an std::map

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map> // if you wanted to do it this way
using namespace std;

int main()
{

   const int MONTHS = 12;
   int days[MONTHS] = { 31, 28, 31, 30,
                        31, 30, 31, 31,
                        30, 31, 30, 31 };
   string m;
   map<string, int> i = { ("January", 0}, "February", 1}, "March", 2},
                        {"April", 3}, {"May", 4}, {"June", 5}, {"July", 6},
                        {"August, 7}", {"September, 8}", {"October, 9}",
                        {"November, 10}", {"December, 11}" };

   cout << "Enter the name of the month: " << endl;
   cin >> m;

   while (m.find(m) == m.end())
   {
       cout << "Invalid month entered! Exit the program to try again." 
            << endl;
       cout << "Enter the name of the month: " << endl;
       cin >> m;

   }

   cout << endl;
   cout << "There are " << days[i[m]] << " days in "
                << m << "." << endl;


   return 0;
}
```